# Can Wubi 12.10 installation be overwritten, but retain the wireless configuration?

Tags: installation, 12.10, wireless, wubi, wine

First time Ubuntu user. I installed Wubi 12.10 and managed to configure the wireless OK using great forum posts.  Then tried to install Wine before doing a Ubuntu update. Got error message of "missing dependencies".  Did Ubuntu update but after that things went downhill. Now locks up if I try to run Wine. But when I tried to use the Ubuntu Software Center to re-install Wine I get message that my "Unlock Keyring Password" isn't correct. I never even had a keyring password when I started.

What I really want to do now is get back to the default original Ubuntu configuration, but keep my wireless intact.

(A) Can I save the wireless setup but load a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10?

or

(B) What steps will I need to take to wipe out the existing Wubi 12.10 installation on the hard drive, and make sure a new installation won't retain some of the corrupted files of the present install?

Answer (score 2):

When re-installing Ubuntu, configuration files are lost. You have to back up your wireless setup. Please check:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1218483

or similar posts that are about the location of the files.

As for Wine I suggest you uninstall it and install PlayOnLinux instead. POL should install a working version of Wine.